# Getting "JSX element type 'App' does not have any construct or call signatures." ts(2604) error when exporting array of JSX Element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom

I've a function that returns array of JSX Elements. When I'm passing this to `ReactDOM.render` I'm getting the above error.

`wrappers.tsx`

```js
const FooterWithStore:React.FC = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <FooterLangWrapper />
    </Provider>
)

const AppWithStore:React.FC = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LangWrapper />
    </Provider>
);

const WrapFooter = (WrappedComponent: React.FC) => [
    <WrappedComponent key="1" />,
    <FooterWithStore key="2" />
]

const App = WrapFooter(AppWithStore)
export default App
```

`index.tsx`

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Try using fragments like below `<></>` is the short hand notation for fragments instead of array something like `<><WrappedComponent key="1" /><FooterWithStore key="2" /></>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution

```
const FooterWithStore:React.FC = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <FooterLangWrapper />
    </Provider>
)

const AppWithStore:React.FC = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LangWrapper />
    </Provider>
);

const WrapFooter = (WrappedComponent: React.FC) => () => [
    <WrappedComponent key="1" />,
    <FooterWithStore key="2" />
]

const App = WrapFooter(AppWithStore)
export default App
```

You need to return the function, and `App` constant contains the object that was formed after the call to `WrapFooter`. Therefore, you just need to use a closure so that the `WrappedComponent` is available in the `WrapFooter` scope.